# Assert C# (socialable) unit test does not use HTTP

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit

We're building some "[sociable](https://blog.jgrossi.com/2018/solitary-or-sociable-testing-events-and-listeners-using-laravel/)" unit tests (tests that are larger than a "unit", but explicitly don't call out to external services or databases). I'm wondering if there is a way in C# to have the test runner throw an exception if a future developer writes a test that does call out.

Unfortunately, our system uses a variety of methods of calling external services -- RestSharp calls, HttpClient calls, WCF service calls, as well as SQL Server. If it was just one, I'd mock it and have an exception thrown, but because I have so many different places it could call out, I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent all of them at once to be sure. (knowing that SQL Server may be a different beast)

Comment: That's an integration test, and the way you do this is by running it in an isolated environment on CI (e.g. deploy your code to Docker container or similar, and then kill all networking on it. If tests fail -> somebody did a whoopsie)

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to block all outgoing traffic for the test runner executable in the firwall.

On the CI machine, add a rule for the test runner executable, for example "nunit3-console.exe", and set it to block all outgoing traffic.

This will not stop people from running stupid tests locally, but the tests will hopefully fail when running on the CI server.

Comment: I feel like this solution would prevent us from running actual integration tests in the future?

Comment: No, you can just have two copies of the test runner executable. Use one copy for the unit tests, another for the integration tests. The firewall rule works with the full path of the executable.